# Django Rest Framework Nested Serializer with One-to-Many unique value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Model for statuses and a Model for storing several languages for each status:

```
class Status(models.Model):
    code = models.IntegerField()

class StatusValueLang(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, related_name="langs", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=3)       
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I have a Model uses Status

```
class Order(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Then, I want to serialize this queryset (get orders with status name in english):

```
orders = Order.objects.filter(status__langs__lang='en')
```

using serializers.Serializer:

```
class StatusValueLangSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    value = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

class StatusSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    langs = StatusValueLangSerializer(many=True)

class OrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    status = StatusSerializer()
```

It works, but because of 'Many=True' in line 'langs = StatusValueLangSerializer(many=True)' StatusSerializer **returns all rows** (languages) despite my filter (status__langs__lang='en')
How I can set Serializers to get this result:

```
[
    {
        "number": "123",
        "status": {
            "langs": [
                {
                    "value" : "Approved" <-- Just one, filtered row. 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

or may be better:

```
[
    {
        "number": "123",
        "status": {
            "value": "Approved"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: You want to get the orders that all of its langs are `en` or get the orders that any of its status langs is `en`?

Comment: StatusValueLang has a constraint 'unique lang for status'. So one status has just one row in specific lang

Answer (score 0):

It is not about the serializers. It's about the query itself. If you're querying on `Order` model, a QuerySet of `Order` objects will be returned.

Assume that there is an order object called `foo`. This `foo` has a status and its status has a lot of langs. So what condition do you expect from your query?

The query you've mentioned in your question: `Order.objects.filter(status__langs__lang='en')` says that give me all `Order`s that their status contains at least one `lang='en'`. The order serializer contains the status serializer and the status serializer contains all of its langs.

In order that you want to show one specific language in your serialized object, you should customize the serializer. Something like this:

```py
>>> class NewOrderSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
...     number = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
...
>>> desired_lang = 'en'
>>> desired_lang_value = StatusValueLang.objects.get(lang='en').value
>>> orders = Order.objects.filter(status__langs__lang=desired_lang)
>>> seriliazed_orders = NewOrderSerializer(orders, many=True)
>>> for order in seriliazed_orders:
...     order['status'] = {'value': desired_lang}
...
>>> print(json.dumps(s, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
[
    {
        "number": "10001",
        "status": {
            "value": desired_lang_value
        }
    }
]
>>>
```

But it is not a good way to do that; This is just a simple way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 1) So is it ok that Serializer cancels queryset's filter in my case? Yes, my condition is 'at least one' but filter surely returns 'one'. 2) Is there any sense to apply Serializer for 'GET' requests like this? Because in the end I have to collect JSON manually

Comment: And you have inaccuracy in getting 'desired_lang_value'. This value depends on status of each order (rejected, pending, approved, etc.). You can't type just `StatusValueLang.objects.get(lang='en').value` because it has several values in english